# WPF Enable/Disable TextBox on click on MenuItem

Tags: c#, wpf, powershell

I have added a ContextMenu to a button; now I want the textbox x:Name=Objektkennzeichen to be set to IsEnabled False or True for the MenuItems at the push of a button.

What do I have to put in Command?

```
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Name}" Value="Objektkennzeichen">
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate>
                                    <DockPanel>
                                        <Grid>
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <TextBox x:Name="Objektkennzeichen" Grid.Column="0" Text="{WPF:ValidatedBinding Value, StringFormat=N}" BorderThickness="1" IsEnabled="false"/>
                                            <Button Name="cmButton" Grid.Column="2" Height="22" Margin="3,0,0,0" Padding="5,0" Command="{Binding DataContext.PsCmd[SetObjektKennzeichen], RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}">
                                                Generieren
                                                <Button.ContextMenu>
                                                    <ContextMenu Name="cm" StaysOpen="true">
                                                    <MenuItem Header="Feld freischalten" Command="Enable = True "/>
                                                    <MenuItem Header="Feld sperren" Command="Enable = False"/>
                                                    </ContextMenu>
                                                </Button.ContextMenu>
                                            </Button>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </DockPanel>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
```

I already tried things like

`Command="{Binding DataContext.PsCmd[CallPowershellFunction], RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"`

but my Programm doesnt run the PSFunction

Comment: You need a Property whose value implements the `System.Windows.Input.ICommand` interface. And that command, in its `Execute`  implementation (most often a callback in a Relay- or DelegateCommand) should do the action desired.
The MenuItem in return should bind to view model property that is modified by that said command.

Comment: Consider replacing Button with ToggleButton. Then you can solve your problem by binding to IsChecked.

Comment: "but my Program doesn't run the Function" - your code does not have this function. And how do we understand why it won’t start?